# Shortcuts for the application switcher in OS X

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, catalina, application-switcher

When I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in OS X (e.g. Catalina) I can access what I believe Apple calls "the application switcher".

- Is there an entry for this shortcut in the `System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts` menu ? (screenshot below). If so, under what name?
- What about the shortcuts to actually go left / right (i.e. choose different applications) within the application switcher?

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, change the shortcuts or learn what they all are?

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin - I'm legitimately interested in knowing if they are defined in that menu, or where they may be - but yes, separately, I'm thinking of changing the shortcuts to actually navigate the apps (Cmd + Tab and Cmd + Shift + Tab) without changing the shortcut to actually open the menu in first place (Cmd + Tab).

Comment: This [CNET article](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/handy-tips-for-mac-application-switcher/) has some additional info on the application switcher.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to change them. They're not in the shortcuts list & they don't have menu equivalents. They're global commands that I imagine you'd need to dig pretty deep into the OS to be able to override.

Answer (score 1):

> - What about the shortcuts to actually go left / right (i.e. choose different applications) within the application switcher?

Release the Command+Tab keys when the highlight is on a selected app to switch to that highlighted app or with the Command key still pressed:

- tab – move selection to the right in the app list
- ` – move selection to the left
- h – hide the selected application
- q – quit the selected application
- mouse scrollwheel – move the selection back and forth
- left arrow – move selection to the left
- right arrow – move selection to the right
- up arrow – enter expose (Mission Control) within the selected application
- down arrow – enter expose (Mission Control) within the selected application

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2009/11/17/secrets-of-the-command-tab-mac-application-switcher/